# Input button action

Tags: html, forms

If I have html forms like:

```
<form>
    <div class="searchbox"><input type="text" name="searchbox" id="searchbox"></div>
    <div class="searchbtn"><input name="search" type="button"></div>
</form>
```

how do I do that when you click on the button search begins without `<input type="submit" />` button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write `JavaScript` code to submit a form.